# How to reload the texts in the UI after enabling location

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, localization, location

I have an app with localization based on the location. It works perfectly if the device location is already enabled. But if it is not, we ask for location permission while opening the aplication. Tf the user clicks yes then I want to change the app language. In this case the current page language is not changing, and the language change will reflect in the remaining pages.

```
<Label Text={"lan:Translate Notification"}>
```

I am binding the static text like this. I have referred this blog: https://mindofai.github.io/Implementing-Localization-with-Xamarin.Forms/

Answer (score 0):

You can handle [Multilingual in Xamarin forms](https://xamgirl.com/handle-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms-without-any-plugin/) with **AppResource File**,the steps are :

**Create an AppResource File**:

Add one resx file per each language you want to support. “It must follow a specific naming convention: use the same filename as the base resources file (eg. AppResources) followed by a period (.) and then the language code”.

**Add your texts in your AppResources file:** code like:

```
<data name="NotesLabel" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Notas:</value>
    <comment>label for input field</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="NotesPlaceholder" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>por ejemplo . comprar leche</value>
    <comment>example input for notes field</comment>
  </data>
```

**Use your AppResources file in your code**:

To use your AppResource texts you have to import the AppResources class namespace in XAML and load it by using static reference.

Here is a article about [Mastering Multilingual in Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/mastering-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms/) which talk about some typical problems that you might face when adding multilingual support .

Answer (score 0):

At the time you have the location service enabled and you've got the current culture info you can:

1. Remove every page inside the navigation stack and load current page again.
2. Restart the application

If your application had run before, you could store the culture info locally (i.e Preference storage) and load the previously known culture at the App.cs before setting the Navigation stack.